# Python descriptor not hooking class level attribute

Tags: python, descriptor

I wanted to make a similar feature to ECMAScript 5 "frozen" object where you can't change anything on it.

Did this:

```
class Fixed(object):
        frzn = 'I AM AWESOME'
        def holdset(_,val):
                _.frzn = _.frzn
                print "frozen is frozen not setting to ", val
        frozen = property(fset=holdset)

        @classmethod
        def __setattr__(self, name, val):
                if name=="frozen":
                        print "You can't unfreeze the frozen"
                else:   
                        self.name = val

dd = Fixed()
dd.frozen = 12312312
dd.frozen = 'AA'
Fixed.frozen = {}
print dd.frozen
print Fixed.frozen
```

Which gives

`You can't unfreeze the frozen
You can't unfreeze the frozen
{}
{}`

The first two assignments fail, when they reference the attribute as an instance member. The third assignment succeeds, when the attribute is referenced as a class member.

I don't understand why.

**How can I make**

`Fixed.frozen = {}`

**Fail in the same way the other assignments did? And why doesn't it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `__setattr__` of the Metaclass. Metaclass is a class that creates a class (Similar to instance created by a class), So, to override things related to class object you need to modify the special methods on the Metaclass.

```
class Meta(type):

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr == "frozen":
            print "You can't unfreeze the frozen"
        else:   
            cls.name = val

class Fixed(object):
        __metaclass__ = Meta
        ...
```